# How to customise the colour of the line using vline or hline?

Tags: matlab

I use the vline script (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1039-hline-and-vline)

to draw vertical lines on my plots. The script allows you to choose the colour of the line and I can make it work for default matlab colours i.e. k, b, g, r, y, o but I'd like to choose a colour that falls outside this range. Is there a way to edit or use the script and choose a custom colour?

E.g. the code for blue dotted lines is
vline([3355, 3325, 3305], {':b', ':b', ':b'})

What if I wanted these lines to be the following purple colour:
purple1 = [204, 153, 255] ./ 255

Comment: Edit the line of the function where `plot` is called. Something like `plot(...,...,'color',[204, 153, 255] ./ 255)`

Comment: If you have MATLA R2018b or later, `hline` and `vline` are official functions. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html You can add `'Color',[r,g,b]` to the call to specify the line color.